# Babun pact checksum error

Tags: cygwin, checksum

I am trying to setup babun following [the official website](http://babun.github.io/), but when I try to install a package, I constantly get a checksum error.

[image]

Additional info :

- babun check is OK
- I tried to use another cygwin mirror, didn't work either

**Edit** 
I tried it on another pc, on a different network, same error has been encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per a user on a babun issues thread:
https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/183#issuecomment-85597677

Replaced

```
# check the md5
digest=`cat "desc" | awk '/^install: / { print $4; exit }'` 
digactual=`md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
if ! [[ $digest == $digactual ]]
then
  echo MD5 sum did not match, exiting
  exit 1
fi
```

in .babun/cygwin/usr/local/bin/pact with

```
# check the verification hash (md5 or sha512)
digest=`cat "desc" | awk '/^install: / { print $4; exit }'`
md5digactual=`md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
shadigactual=`sha512sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
if ! [[ $digest == $md5digactual || $digest == $shadigactual ]]
then
  echo Verification hash did not match, exiting
  exit 1
fi
```

That got me up and working until they merge the commit. Since I'm running from a release I'll have to work on converting to the live Git version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue that has been corrected 2 days ago.
See https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/257

Comment: Oh thanks, so I guess the compiled version is still buggy. I will try with git to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in version 1.1.0. Just execute 'babun update.